# right click event for wxDataViewListCtrl

Tags: c++, mouseevent, wxwidgets

Originally in wxDataViewListCtrl it supports event of the right click only on the headers.
I would like to let the table also react when I right click on it and a menu pops up.

Neither Bind nor Connect works.

What do I actually miss to add this event to the ctrl?

Neither

```cpp
Bind(wxEVT_RIGHT_DOWN, &MyClass::MyFunc, this, ID_DATA_VIEW_LIST_CTRL)
```

nor

```cpp
Connect(ID_DATA_VIEW_LIST_CTRL, wxEVT_RIGHT_DOWN,
    wxMouseEventHandler(MyClass::MyFunc), NULL, this)
```

works to make the DataViewListCtrl react to mouse right click.

Comment: With wxDataViewCtrl/wxDataViewListCtrl there is a special event you can use for this `wxEVT_DATAVIEW_ITEM_CONTEXT_MENU`.

Comment: @NewPagodi Thank you for the comment. I somehow misread the description of this one when I was implementing the event for headers, and even thought I have to implement a custom wxDataViewRenderer just for this event. Now it works well.